# Who is L. A. Balashov?

Tags: ho.history-overview

I refer to the mathematician described here:

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=eng&personid=19612

I am interested in learning, e.g., his full name.

Comment: Wow, google's indexing is fast. This is already one of the top hits on google for "mathematician balashov".

Comment: He was one of my tutors in Functional Analysis (1988-89) in the Moscow Lomonosov State University. But I have to admit how bad is my memory on names. I remember that he passed away around 2000 or so, quite suddenly.

Comment: It seems that the link I provided has since been updated with Balashov's full name (which makes the original question as stated now seem confusing).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is fantastic to learn how easy people are forgotten.
I made several calls to the Faculty of Mechanics and Mathematics
of the Moscow Lomonosov State University (including the Human
Resources and the Chair of Function Theory and Functional Analysis
where Balashov worked till his sudden death) without success.
I have just received a letter from Boris Sergeevich Kashin
(I indicate his full name because of the question) who
says that Balashov was Leonid Alekseevich (but he is not sure
about the patronymic name, so he will write me back later).
I will add more if some further information arrives.

Comment: Thanks Wadim!  His 1970/1971 review of Walsh series with Rubinshtein was quite helpful to me.  He seems to have had quite a few papers so I was a bit surprised that it was so hard to find out much about him.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the full names of most of Soviet mathematicians on the site http://www.mathnet.ru (there is also Balashov).

Comment: See Ryan O'Donnell's Sep 27 comment to his question.

Comment: @jc: I read the Ryan O'Donnell's comment, but I give a more general answer/adviсe.

Comment: Boris, after getting Balashov's name from Kashin, it was decided to update the information on mathnet.ru